# Spring Data Reactive Mongo: Class type converter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring boot 2 webflux with reactive mongo repository. I'm trying to persist and query entities with `Class<>` field type. But I can't figure out how to configure my application to work with this type.
Here is my entity that I would like to store in mongo:

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Data
public class ServiceEntity {

  @Id
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private Class inputClass;
}
```

And here is my mongo configuration:

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClientSettings;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.bson.BsonReader;
import org.bson.BsonWriter;
import org.bson.codecs.Codec;
import org.bson.codecs.DecoderContext;
import org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecProvider;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class MongoConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public MongoClientSettings settings() {
    log.debug("Configure mongo settings");
    return MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .codecRegistry(CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
            CodecRegistries.fromProviders(new ClassCodecProvider()),
            MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry()))
        .build();
  }

  //  @Bean
  public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
    log.debug("Configure mongo custom conversions");
    return new MongoCustomConversions(asList(new StringToClassConverter()));
  }

  private static class ClassCodec implements Codec<Class> {

    @Override
    public Class decode(BsonReader reader, DecoderContext decoderContext) {
      try {
        return Class.forName(reader.readString());
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new MongoException("Couldn't read value as class type", e);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void encode(BsonWriter writer, Class value, EncoderContext encoderContext) {
      writer.writeString(value.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Class> getEncoderClass() {
      return Class.class;
    }
  }

  private static class ClassCodecProvider implements CodecProvider {

    @Override
    public <T> Codec<T> get(Class<T> clazz, CodecRegistry registry) {
      if (clazz == Class.class) {
        return (Codec<T>) new ClassCodec();
      }
      return null;
    }
  }

  private static class StringToClassConverter implements Converter<String, Class> {

    @Override
    public Class convert(String source) {
      try {
        return Class.forName(source);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new MongoException("Couldn't read string as class type", e);
      }

    }
  }

}
```

The problem is when I try to read entities from mongo I get error:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Class<?>]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:887)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1392)
```

Also I created String to Class converter (see `StringToClassConverter` in the config) and tried to use it as custom converter. But when I put such configuration to the context(to do that uncomment `@Bean` annotation on `customConversions()` method) it had been used for any string conversion. As result, while saving entities:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Class<?>] for value 'service1'; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException: Couldn't read string as class type
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:46)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleWrite(MappingMongoConverter.java:849)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeSimpleInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:829)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:488)
```

Full code is available on [github](https://github.com/bullet-tooth/mongoclasspertist). Please see `com.example.mongoclasspertist.ServiceRepositoryTest#test` to reproduce.

I see next ways how to solve this problem(but them could lead to another issues probably) by submitting PR to Spring repo:
* To Create `ClassToStringConverter` and `StringToClassConverter` in `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoConverters`
* To change `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter#getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleWrite` method logic for converting only if source and target types are applicable to custom converter.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the annotation [`@ReadingConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/convert/ReadingConverter.html) on the converter seems to do the job. Please give it a try.

```
@ReadingConverter
private static class StringToClassConverter implements Converter<String, Class> 
{
```

Comment: Will it be a spring bean? Can one inject dependencies into it?